# Why this refers to window object in this javascript example?

Tags: javascript, this

I'm trying to understand where am i mistaking ! I have the small ***javascript*** object like this:

```
o = {
    fun: function (x) {
        return x();
    },

    fun2: function () {
        return this;
    }
};
```

Now i'm triggering the method below in ***chrome debugger***:

```
o.fun(o.fun2);
```

this returns a ***window object***. I'm expecting to see the ***o object***. I couldn't figure this out. could someone explain this to me ? I really want to know what is happening behind the scene by javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `this` is determined by the way a function is called, and by *nothing else*.  The fact that your functions are defined by initialization expressions as part of that object literal makes absolutely no difference.

You can ensure that the value of `this` propagates from "fun" like this:

```
fun: function (x) {
    return x.call(this);
},
```

Comment: Thank you for your brief answer. well as i know, when i run "o.fun2()" i get the "o" object. well all that happening (as i know) here is that i just direct that output to "o.fun2" method !

Comment: Thank you, you were right. for others like me who has the same misunderstanding, The problem lies in "return x();" line. when you are firing a function or method, you should remember, THE WAY YOU FIRE YOUR FUNCTION INDICATES THIS VALUE. in here i just wrote "x()". it doesn't matter where you wrote "x()" whether it is in the body of one object's method or right below your script tag, it always refers to window object.